# Do all words need a particle?

Tags: particles

I'm trying to figure out if question words need particles. For example

```
なぜ　(should there be a particle here?) にほんご　を　べんきょうしますか？
Why study Japanese?
```

Should there be a particle after なぜ? If so which one? If no particle is needed could you say why that is.

Thanks.

Comment: なぜ is an adverb.  Compare another question word, 誰【だれ】, which is not.

Comment: We'd normally say it as なぜ、にほんごをべんきょうするんですか.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking multiple questions.

1. Do all words need a particle?
   A: Of course not. Verbs such as べんきょうします, and many others, appear without a particle.
2. Should there be a particle after なぜ?
   A: If "should" means "is required", then no.
3. If no particle is need, why?
   A: It's difficult to give the reason why something is **not** the case. Particles fulfill certain grammatical functions, such as marking case, syntactic relationship, etc., or pragmatic functions, such as speech acts (questions, requests, etc.), or illocutionary force (～よ, ～ね, etc.), etc. なぜ is an interrogative adverb, and hence appears without a particle.

Also note that some, but not all, particles can be dropped in casual speech.